# Apache OLTU - production ready or not?

Tags: java, oauth, jersey, oltu

I can't quite figure out whether Apache OLTU (http://oltu.apache.org/ - Java OAuth 2 implementation) is production ready or not. The distribution files on the Download page all currently end in *-0.22-incubating.zip. Does anyone have experience with Jersey 2.4.1 + Apache OLTU 0.22 in a production environment? Would it be better to go with the OAuth 1 implementation that already ships with Jersey and wait until OAuth 2 is also implemented?

Comment: From responses I received on the user@oltu.apache.org mailing list, I've gathered that the latest version is 0.31 and available via Maven - http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Coltu. OLTU also seems to be used in production by at least two user@oltu.apache.org subscribers. There are also two commercial OLTU-based OAuth offerings: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Commercial+Apache+Oltu+Offerings

Comment: any update on this? I'm looking to use Apache OLTU with Jersey as well for oauth 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this answer is a year late, I hope anyone still looking for Apache Oltu will find this useful.

Apache Oltu has made a production release version 1.0.0 around March 2014. This supports OAuth 2. So, you can now use Apache Oltu for your projects. You can get it from Maven Central at http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Capache%20oltu.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Sajux. I've used Apache Oltu in my project for Spring Security OAuth2 implementation and works very greatly. The latest release Version (1.0.0) release in March-14. It has the major 12 usage listed here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.oltu.oauth2/org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client/1.0.0/usages

The Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle Dependency:

```
'org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.0'
```

You can refer quick start guide from development perspective. Here you go: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Client+Quickstart

Answer (score 0):

It's implementing the draft 10 of OAuth 2.0 spec.

Before RFC 6749 was finalized, there were many drafts for the OAuth 2.0 spec. And apache OLTU is implementing it's 10th draft, not the final spec of OAuth 2.0 i.e. RFC 6749. And 10th draft is different from the final [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

You can find all the [drafts of OAuth 2.0 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2)

Comment: How does this answer the question? It appears to be a clarification, not a self-contained answer.